# Unable to search through python web scraper (URL doesn't change on search)

Tags: python, selenium, url, web-scraping, search

I'm unable to search through the search bar given on the site. It takes the zip/postal code of area and return the list of available shops(relative).

But unlike most of the sites the site I am working on doesn't change the URL on the event we put a string and search from the search box given on the site.
I've tried through many different techniques including using selenium and Action Chains but all in vain.

Please, anyone see if you can find a way.
I would appreciate the help.

Here's the samples that I've tried

```
# /// remaining code///

search_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, "partnerfinder-search"))
)

search_element = driver.find_element_by_id("partnerfinder-search")

action.send_keys(postal_code) # postal_code is just a character string
action.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

# also tried these
action.send_keys("12")
# action.send_keys_to_element(search_element, "12")
# action.send_keys_to_element(search_element, Keys.ENTER)

# /// remaining code///
```

other method

```
# /// remaining code///

driver.get('URL')

search_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='search']")

#also tried this
# search_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@class='location-search__form']/input[@name='search']")

action.move_to_element(search_element)
action.send_keys(postal_code)
action.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
action.perform()

# /// remaining code///
```

Also tried a bunch of other solutions but non seems to be working.

Comment: Can you give me the sample zip code for testing ?

Comment: also what is the requirement if the URL does not change, Is that stopping you to do anything ?

Comment: I understand it does not change for me either, I would like to know the reason where you are stuck cause of that ?

Comment: when I try to put some string in the search box through python scraper it doesn't work. Means it does not respond or provide any feedback in return. Just stays on the same page/form.

As it should show the results of the search in respond.

Comment: One more thing if its of any help, unlike other sites, try to hover the cursor over the search box while looking at its HTML class " <div class="location-search location-search--fullscreen"> " it also changes to "  <div class="location-search location-search--fullscreen hovered"> "

Comment: Do you just to search something and based on search result you want to scrape something ?

Comment: yes, that's right.

Comment: Had any luck bro?
@cruisepandey

Comment: I get this with automation ` Bitte wählen Sie einen Bereich.` What language is that ?

Comment: I also tried `driver.get("https://www.hansgrohe.de/#partner-finder")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 50)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class$='js-accept-all']"))).click()

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "partnerfinder-search"))).send_keys('566')

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//i[@class='icon-crosshair'])[2]/.."))).click()

for distance in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.pf__item-distance span"):
  print(distance.text)`

Comment: German

Bitte wählen Sie einen Bereich. = "please select an area"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That worked for me:

***python***

```
# remaining code

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 50)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class$='js-accept-all']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "partnerfinder-search"))).send_keys('01067', ' ')
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.minimize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.maximize_window()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='pac-container pac-logo']/div[@class='pac-item']"))).click()

wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='pf__item']")))

content = driver.page_source

# remaining code
```

thanks for all your help @cruisepanday